# Hibernate mapping for different items in the same table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following three classes `[Promotion, Product and Image]`. `Promotion` has an `Image`. `Product` has list/collection of `Image's`.  In the future there may be new classes that also has `Image` or Collection of `Image's`.

I would like to put all images in the same image table `(eg:: image_table)`. It means that the image of `Promotion` and the collection of images in `Product` are all going to go into the same table.

I can't put for instance two `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne` annotations in `Image` class because then there will be two different foreign keys `(Promotion_FK and Product_FK)` in Image table `(eg:: image_table)`. In the future if there are more classes that has image then I have to add additional  `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne` annotations.

1. Is there a way to map this feature in Hibernate?
2. If my design is not good, in the real world how do they store images that belongs to different classes in the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Unidirectional mapping then

e.g. 
**Promotion** having **Image**, **Product** having **Image**'s, **but not** Vice Versa

Comment: @Shantaram Tupe Then on the Image side how will the image table look like? For instance i will have: [imageId, p_FK, filename, width, height]. p_FK column will contain both Promotion IDs and Product IDs. Is that correct?

Comment: no,Using Unidirectional Mapping, at Image side it only contains **[imageId,  filename, width, height]**, you can not access `Promotion` or `Product` through `Image` entity...but you can access `Image` entity through `Promotion` or `Product` or `Further classes`, using `imageId`, of particular entities...