# Hibernate @OneToMany Mapping - issues with deleting records

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In my application I would like to put all images in the application in one table. I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359899/hibenate-mapping-for-different-items-in-the-same-table) last time and someone recommended that I use **unidirectional** `@OneToMany`.

I have the following entities which are associated with `Image` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="promotion")
public class Promotion {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    protected String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="itemId")
    protected List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>(); 
}


@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    protected String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="itemId")
    protected List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>(); 
}


@Entity
@Table(name="image")
public class Image{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id = IdGenerator.createId();

    @Column(name="itemId")
    private String itemId;

    @Column(name="title", nullable = false)
    protected String title;

    @Column(name="filename", nullable = false)
    protected String filename;

    @Column(name="path", unique = true)
    private String path;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    protected int width;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    protected int height;
}
```

Issues am facing now are:

**A)**
When I use `cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` on the **images ArrayList** attributes I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

So I replaced it with `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` and when I save `Product` or `Promotion` the associated `Image(s)` are saved as well which is cool and that is what I want

**B)**
The main problem I have now is when I delete a `Product` or `Promotion`, its associated images never get deleted. Their associated images stays in the **image** table.

By using `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` I expect that when I delete a `Product` or a `Promotion`, its images should also be deleted automatically. I tried to delete an image from the database if it will trigger its associated `Product` or `Promotion` to be deleted but it didn't since I think it is unidirectional which makes sense. But how come when I delete a `Product` or a `Promotion` its associated images don't get deleted

Comment: Hi Eddy. I am a volunteer editor here, and I have amended a few of your posts for readability. It'd be great if you could check out the edits I make, and read the edit messages, so you can avoid those problems in the future. You may not be aware, but question+answers here are not primarily for question authors - they are for the many hundreds of future readers of your questions. With this in mind, we want posts to be as readable as possible.

Comment: There's two items I'd recommend to you, with your writing style in mind. Firstly there is no need to add thanks and appreciation and other chatty material - [keep it succinct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) please. Secondly, please observe the usual case rules for English; in particular, when referring to yourself as "I", it is always a capital letter. Do you think you could make a small adjustment on these two things in your future material? It would save me, and other editors, some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `orphanRemoval = true` in both relationships:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true)
```

This will

> apply the remove operation to entities that have been removed from the
>   relationship and to cascade the remove operation to those entities.